# React Native - How to pass image as file to server using multi form data

Tags: react-native

I don't know the problem here. Just a background I'm using image picker to select a photo and to upload my file

In my screen, it's working as expected the image is displaying properly but upon calling the endpoint I always get error `400` and says "Bad request"

Here's my code

```
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';

const openImageLibrary = async () => {
    const options = {
      mediaType: 'photo',
    };

    const response = await new Promise(resolve => {
      launchImageLibrary(options, resolve);
    });

    if (!response) {
      return null;
    }

    const source = {uri: response.assets[0].uri};
    const {type, uri, name} = response.assets[0];
    setImageSource(source);

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('id', data.id);
    formData.append('isPrimary', 'true');
    formData.append(
      'file',
      JSON.stringify({
        uri: uri,
        type: type,
        name: name,
      }),
    );

    try {
      const uploadResponse = await axios.post(
        'my-api-url',
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        },
      );

      console.log('Upload successful', uploadResponse.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Upload error', error);
    }
  };
```

Upon triggering the axios payload is complete and looks like this

Under Form Data

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryGN310uQmaUmZozaY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

fef70a-46-4002d-4d5333-8fca-4-9f3e-2f20
------WebKitFormBoundaryGN310uQmaUmZozaY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="isPrimary"

true
------WebKitFormBoundaryGN310uQmaUmZozaY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

{"uri":"file:///Users/myFolder/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1098039E-00EB-48B4-9152-00FA2CB9E1F7/data/Containers/Data/Application/B7F8A6D3-889B-4C29-8C9E-958E9C7C7945/tmp/462EA4BC-4163-4469-B613-67F4184DA8A8.jpg","type":"image/jpg"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryGN310uQmaUmZozaY--
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to post an image from react native to django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77422798/how-to-post-an-image-from-react-native-to-django)

Comment: I tried to check the link, but no

Comment: Remove JSON.stringify for starters. Make sure uri, name and type proper values.

Comment: If i remove it the payload that will be pass for file is [Object Object]